# How can a probability 0 event occur an infinite number of times?

Tags: probability, geometry

I was watching the following Lex Fridman Interview on YouTube : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=reYdQYZ9Rj4

At @1:04:45 in the video, the following discussion happens:

- Probability 0 can happen Infinitely often
- Imagine a Unit Square on the Plane
- Suppose I use a Measure (Probability Measure) in which the Area of the Region is its Probability
- I draw a Curve in the Unit Square, it (the Curve?) has a Measure of 0 but Infinitely many Points
- Therefore, Probability 0 can happen Infinitely often

I am trying to understand why this example is true and how does it support the argument that "An event with probability 0 can happen infinitely Often".

Using Python code, I tried to draw an picture that corresponds to this discussion:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig, ax = plt.subplots()


ax.set_xlim(-0.5, 1.5)
ax.set_ylim(-0.5, 1.5)


square = plt.Rectangle((0, 0), 1, 1, fill=False, edgecolor='black', linewidth=2)
ax.add_patch(square)


ax.set_xlabel('x')
ax.set_ylabel('y')


ax.text(0, 0, '(0, 0)', ha='right', va='top')
ax.text(1, 0, '(1, 0)', ha='left', va='top')
ax.text(0, 1, '(0, 1)', ha='right', va='bottom')
ax.text(1, 1, '(1, 1)', ha='left', va='bottom')


ax.text(0.5, 0.5, 'Area = 1', ha='center', va='center')


ax.grid(True)


from matplotlib.ticker import MaxNLocator
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(MaxNLocator(integer=True))


x = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
y = x**2
ax.plot(x, y, color='red')

x_points = np.arange(0, 1.05, 0.05)
y_points = x_points**2
ax.scatter(x_points, y_points, color='red', s=10)


plt.show()
```

[image]

Based on this picture, I can understand the following:

- The Square has an Area of 1
- The Curve has Infinitely many Points
- We had mentioned that the Area is 1 and the Probability Measure is the Area - therefore, the Measure should be 1

**But this is what I do not understand:**

- But why does the Curve have a Probability Measure of 0 just because its passing through a Square with Measure of 1?
- And how exactly does this picture prove that an Event with Probability 0 can happen infinitely many times?

Can someone please help me understand this?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-probability/zero-probability-events

Comment: Even simpler — every realization of a continuous random variable is a zero probability event.

Comment: 'Probability 0 can happen Infinitely often' is a sentence with no meaning

Comment: It is pointless to ponder about the meaning of that isolated sentence. In what sense it has a meaning Fridman and your line example in a plane have explained. In short and again: zero probability albeit containing uncountable points. Let's move on.

Comment: Probability zero events are indeed very weird, especially when the were talking uncountable infinities. Posted an answer to help make that a bit more concrete.  Probability zero events are not impossible, just vanishingly unlikely.

Comment: An interesting extension of Lex's example would be if we didn't just use any curve, but a space-filling curve -- in which case it's area is 1, contains all the points, but any finite segment of that curve has area 0.

Comment: I don't get why this is keeps getting downvoted as not enough context -- its pretty clear what is being asked....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to pick a random point in the unit square then there are uncountably many such points. The uniform probability measure on the unit square is just the Lebesgue measure for $\mathbb{R^2}$ (i.e., the area of the set being)

Points and lines in the plane have area 0 and hence probability measure 0.

However, these points are still perfectly valid points so they have the potential to be chosen. However, it is vanishingly unlikely that they will be chosen. This is true for every point on the line (also an uncountable set).

Part of the challenge here is that uncountable infinity is very counterintuitive.

One way think about a probability zero event $A$ is as the expected value of the indicator random variable $1_{A}$ defined on the unit square.

Let $X$ be a uniform random variable on the unit square. Then we have

$$E[1_A] = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac1n \sum_1^n 1_A(X_i) =0$$

So the *fraction* of times $A$ happens in an iid sequence converges almost surely to $0$. So if we kept taking larger and larger iid samples of $X$ we'd see $X_i \in A$ becomes a vanishingly small proportion of our sample.

Taking this one step further, consider the sum of the indicator functions:

$$S_n:= \sum_1^n 1_A(X_i)$$

Since the $1_A(X_i)$ are iid, we can invoke the [Borel-Cantelli Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel%E2%80%93Cantelli_lemma)
$$\text{Let $E_n$ be a sequence of events then} \sum_1^{\infty} P(E_n) < \infty \implies P\left(\lim_{n \to \infty}\sup E_n\right) = 0 \;\text{(i.e., a finite number of $E_n$ will occur, almost surely)}$$

to show that $$P\left( \lim_{n \to \infty} S_n <\infty\right) = 1$$

*Proof*

$$P(1_{A}(X_i)=1)=0 \implies \sum_1^{\infty} P(1_{A}(X_i)=1) = 0 < \infty \implies P\left(\lim_{n \to \infty} \sup 1_{A}(X_i)\right) = 0$$

Which means that even in countably infinite samples you'd see $A$ only occur a finite number of times (almost surely -- still possible that you hit it infinitely often).

A similar conclusion is demonstrated in these two papers:

Lemma 3 (Page 4, item G) and the section right at the top of pdf page 5 which relates this to infinite sums of indicator variables: [https://viterbi-web.usc.edu/~mjneely/Borel-Cantelli-LLN.pdf](https://viterbi-web.usc.edu/%7Emjneely/Borel-Cantelli-LLN.pdf)

And corollary 2.3 here: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-304-undergraduate-seminar-in-discrete-mathematics-spring-2015/2dc1c9e37d402c000b628ee85e2228d1_MIT18_304S15_project2.pdf

Comment: Not sure why I got a downvote here -- this is a pretty straightforward explanation but if I misstated something please let me know.

Comment: I'll re-link a nice explainer here: https://www.statlect.com/fundamentals-of-probability/zero-probability-events

Comment: And on the use of indicator variables:https://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall06/cos341/handouts/variance-notes.pdf